# Why can't I remove item from this Array using slice or lodash remove?

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash, splice

Using slice (In this situation I find the correct item in the Array, attempt slice, but the Array stays exactly the same):

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.storedViews.length; i++) {
    if (view_id === vm.storedViews[i].id) {
        vm.storedViews.slice(i,1);
        // vm.storedViews = _.remove(vm.storedViews, i);
        break;
    }
}

console.log('vm.storedViews',vm.storedViews);
```

Using `_.remove` all items end up being removed from my Array:

```
for (var i=0; i<vm.storedViews.length; i++) {
    if (view_id === vm.storedViews[i].id) {
        // vm.storedViews.slice(i,1);
        vm.storedViews = _.remove(vm.storedViews, i);
        break;
    }
}

console.log('vm.storedViews',vm.storedViews);
```

[image]

Comment: `.slice` doesn't modify the array, it returns a **new** array containing the selected elements.

Comment: To modify the array you use `.splice()`.

Comment: Ah that was the answer! `splice` want to post it? I am curious why remove for lodash didn't work either, bonus for that :)

Comment: @LeonGaban you're iterating over an array while modifying it. After you removed an element its indexes shift. Not only that - `_.remove` returns the removed elements, not kept. The proper lodash solution would be to use `filter` and simply filter only elements you want.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.splice()` to modify the array. `.slice` just returns the selected elements.

```
vm.storedViews.splice(i, 1);
```

`_.remove()` didn't work because the the second argument is not an index, it's a predicate function -- it removes all elements of the array for which the function returns a truthy value. It looks like the closest lodash function to `.splice()` is [`_.pullAt()`](https://lodash.com/docs#pullAt). It takes a list of array indexes to remove, so you can use it for your case where you just want to remove one element:

```
_.pullAt(vm.storedViews, i);
```

Instead of your `for` loop you can use `_.findIndex()`:

```
_.pullAt(vm.storedViews, _.findIndex(vm.storedViews, 'id', view_id));
```

If the IDs are unique, you can also use:

```
_.remove(vm.storedViews, 'id', view_id);
```

Comment: I think this is my first foray into lodash. The documentation is very nice.

Comment: Thanks! I love `lodash`, look at that :) replaced a for loop with a 1 liner!